# When to release a class with delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

A quick question to delegates. Lets say, CLASSA has a delegate defined:

```
@protocol MyDelegate
   -(void) didFinishUploading;
@end
```

In CLASSB I create an instance of CLASS A

```
-(void) doPost { 
    CLASSA *uploader = [[CLASSA alloc] init];
    uploader.delegate = self;  // this means CLASSB has to implement the delegate
    uploader.post; 
}
```

and also in CLASSB:

```
-(void)didFinishUploding {
}
```

So when do I have to release the uploader? Because when I release it in doPost, it is not valid anymore in didFinishUploading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating **CLASSA** instance in **doPost** method.
It is better to create `CLASSA *uploader = [[CLASSA alloc] init];` in the **init** method and release *uploader* in **dealloc**.

make `uploader` as member variable.

```
    -(id) init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
          uploader = [[CLASSA alloc] init];
          uploader.delegate = self;

        }
        retrurn self;
    }

    -(void) doPost 
     {
        uploader.post;
     }

   -(void)didFinishUploding
    {
       uploader.delegate = nil;
       //your code
    }

    -(void) dealloc
    {
       [uploader release];
       [super dealloc];
    }
```

Comment: i figured out that it is also a good idea to set the class.delegate no nil when releasing it

Answer (score 1):

Release it in `didFinishUploding`.  Put `CLASSA * uploader` in the instance variables of CLASSB to allow for that.